# How can I send server errors to the client?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, passport.js

I use passport.js and I write all the necessary code, but I don't understand how I can put the error in the client-side? The `successRedirect` is doing alright, but if I put a wrong password nothing happens and no message is displayed.

#### passport-config.js

This is the function where I initialize the `LocalStrategy`

```js
const LocalStratigy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const initialize = (passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) => {
  const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
    const user = getUserByEmail(email) //dont worry we cana emplimate this function latter 
    if (user == null) {
      return done(null, false, {
        messege: "No user with that email"
      }) //done are a function used in the parameter 
    }
    try {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user)
      } else {
        return done(null, false, {
          messege: "wrrong password "
        })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return done(error)
    }
  }
  passport.use(new LocalStratigy({
    usernameField: 'email'
  }, authenticateUser))
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id))
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    return done(null, getUserById(id))
  })
}

module.exports = initialize
```

#### serveur.js

This server-side

```js
app.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/signin',
  failureFlash: true
}))
```

#### signin.html

In this file, I use js code in the script but it doesn't work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="signup.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="messeges">
  </div>
  <form action="signin" method="post">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="from">
        <h2>Sign in</h2>
        <div class="inputbox">
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required">
          <span>Email Adress</span>
          <i></i>
        </div>
        <div class="inputbox">
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required="required">
          <span>Password</span>
          <i></i>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
          <a href="./signup.html">Forgot Password</a>
          <a href="./signup.html">sign up</a>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script>
    const messege = document.getElementById('messeges')
    if (messages.error) {
      messege.innerHTML = "<h1>messages.error</h1>"
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the app.post like this:

```
app.post('/signin', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/signin?error=Invalid email or password',
    failureFlash: true
  })(req, res, next)
})
```

and possibly make messages div a bit more robust:

```
<div id="messages">
  <% if (messages && messages.error) { %>
    <h1><%= messages.error %></h1>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

and remove the script tag in your html. Also add this to the serveur.js to parse the request body in your server-side code.:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: no bro stell not working maybe this code is not correct – 
<div id="messages">
  <% if (messages && messages.error) { %>
    <h1><%= messages.error %></h1>
  <% } %>
</div>

Comment: possibly this could work:

<div id="messages">
  <% if (typeof messages !== 'undefined' && messages.error) { %>
    <h1><%= messages.error %></h1>
  <% } %>
</div>